# Digital Computer Architecture Help Needed

Tags: cpu-architecture

let's say I have a 2-Mbyte chip and need to construct a 8-Mbyte memory. I need to show the address lines in a diagram and explain what the address lines are used for. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly you could make it with 4 2-Mbyte chips.

The first 2 bits of the address are used to select which chip you need. Then the rest of the address is sent to the selected chip.